# get the value of an url response with curl

Tags: php, curl

I am using PHP curl method to get a string type response. To create the request I use:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, $data);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if($response === false)
    throw new Exception(__CLASS__."::".__FUNCTION__."_".$err);
return $response;
```

Why I always receive a bool(true) response instead of the string I echo from the other side?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by '"true" response'? Is $response the string "true", or is it boolean true?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you already have

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

in your code. curl_exec should already returns the content of the page instead of a BOOL.

This is a snippet of a library I use. As pointed out this might not be needed but it helped me out once...

```
//The content - if true, will not download the contents
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
```

Also it seems to have some bugs related to CURLOPT_NOBODY (which might explain why you have this issue):

- http://osdir.com/ml/web.curl.general/2005-07/msg00073.html
- http://curl.haxx.se/mail/curlphp-2008-03/0072.html

Comment: He wants the body to be returned, with `CURLOPT_NOBODY` the body won't even be downloaded.

Comment: This is why it is set to FALSE. If set to TRUE it will not download any content read more carefully before voting down!

Comment: Ok you're right. Still, the default for `CURLOPT_NOBODY` is false so there's no need to set this. Also, you're supposed to explain your answer -- I even had to scroll your code to the right before I could read that comment.

Comment: Great! Removed my downvote. Can't vote up apparently, "vote can't be changed unless answer is edited". Duh...

Comment: No problem. I just hope that my asnwer / our comments will help solve question.