# Hot to read the JSON url in php using CURL?

Tags: php, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get the value of an url response with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001897/get-the-value-of-an-url-response-with-curl)

I have the json url as follow

```
www.example.com/hello.php?action=get&id=18&format=json
```

which returns output as `{"id":18,"name":"Dharma"}`.

How can I get the name property by using php curl function?

I want output as "Dharma".

Comment: Thx i am trying to get the out by using CURL in php

Comment: `$str = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/hello.php?action=get&id=18&format=json'); $json = json_decode($str, TRUE); echo $json['name'];`

Comment: By Using Curl you can only get the JSON data not retreive any info from it unless you do a brute force method and split it , JSON decode is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

You don't need cURL for that, simply use

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/hello.php?action=get&id=18&format=json‌'); 
$array = json_decode($str, TRUE); 
echo $array['name'];
```

Comment: Thanks. I am learning CURL that's why i am expecting the result in only CURL in php

Comment: @AnithaSelvam It does not matter which one you use. Think. The important part is the `json_decode()`.

Comment: The person posting the question specifically requested an example of cUrl usage. They said they're learning curl - don't see anything wrong if someone is wanting to learn something.

Comment: That $str should be $content, then it works!